# remove/hide <p> with specific content?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I imported hundreds of posts from Drupal to WordPress, and they all came in nicely. I did not create the content on Drupal, and I'm discovering that all of the posts have multiple

[image]

statements at the top, which is driving down the top of the content with blank lines. These are appearing in the inspector as

[image]

I can't edit each of these hundreds of posts, so I'm hoping there's a way with code (CSS (unlikely), JavaScript?) to hide any p with that character/code as its only content.

Tried CSS, but can't hide things like this with it.

Comment: [Ideally you could use `p:empty { display: none; }`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) however [as of 2023 browsers still don't support using `:empty` in this way](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_empty_matches_whitespace) - so you'll need to use JS. However, why not just use a regex against your database to batch-update the HTML to remove the redundant elements in the source?

Comment: Why not just run something like this against your WordPress DB? (make a backup first, of course!):  `UPDATE articles SET content = REGEX_REPLACE( content, '<p>\s*</p>', ''  ) WHERE REGEXP_LIKE( content, '<p>\s*</p>' );`

Comment: If you have [wp-cli](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/) installed on your server, run `wp search-replace '<p>&nbsp;</p>' '' wp_posts --dry-run`. This will remove all of that from your content. The `--dry-run` flag is a safety - basically runs the query without executing. If all looks good run the command again without `--dry-run`

Comment: Using JS on the front end is certainly possible. For the sake of efficiency, how are posts being inserted into the DOM, and do post container elements  have a unique CSS selector suitable for use in `element.querySelectorAll` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can u the code below to remove all tags with only contain space inside:

```
const isNotMarked = el => {
        while (el && el.parentNode && !el.parentNode.marked) {
           el = el.parentNode;
           if (el.marked) { return false }
        }
        return true;
    }
    [...document.querySelectorAll("span, p, strong")]
        .filter(el => el.textContent.trim() === "" && isNotMarked(el) ? el.marked = true : false)
        .forEach(el => el.parentNode.removeChild(el));
```